# How to search 2 fields for 2 different keywords? Lucene.net

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

How could i perform a search like this in `Lucene.net`?

Return all results where `Title` field equals "someTitle" and where `isPrivate` field equals "false"?

I guess that i could create 2 indexes, one with all documents and one with only the non-private ones. But it would be even better if it would be possible to do it with only 1 index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this readily using the [QueryParser's query syntax](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html):

```
+Title:someTitle +isPrivate:false
```

Or by combining the two terms to be searched in a [BooleanQuery](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d8/d7c/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_boolean_query.html):

```
BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();
bq.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("Title", "someTitle"), Occur.MUST);
bq.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("isPrivate", "false"), Occur.MUST);
```